# ExtentReports/Klov and Serenity

Tags: serenity-bdd, extentreports, cucumber-serenity, selenium-extent-report

Does anybody know if ExtentReports specifically Klov  provide support for Serenity? I am looking to implement this dashboard and would like to know if Serenity is supported by it.

Comment: There is a cucumber adapter created by community already. Not a lot of users use serenity in comparison but creating an adapter for it shouldnt be too tricky.